# On click of button another method is called before the actual method is called

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat, table, method

Im new to salesforce. I have just started with apex and Vf. I have built one vf where on page load it fetches account list and displays it in table. Before displaying it in table it calls another function Details(). I have one button in page. When i click that button it calls the method submit() and performs some operations and navigates to another vf. But the problem is When i click button it executes Details() method first then executes Submit() method. But I want to call only submit() method not details(). Why it calls Details method every time i click submit? How can i prevent calling details method on submit?

Thanks in advance.

I have attached sample vf and apex controller

```
<apex:page controller="SampleCode">
<apex:form>
    <apex:repeat value="{!AccountList}" var="a">
        <apex:outputField value="{! a.Name}"/>  
    </apex:repeat>
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{! submit}"/>
</apex:form>
```

```
public class SampleCode {
public List<Account> Accounts=new List<Account>();
public List<Account> getAccountList(){

    Accounts=[Select Id,Name from Account];
    Details();
    Return Accounts;
}
public pageReference submit(){
    system.debug(2);
    //code here to perform operation;
    //navigate to another page
}

public void Details(){
    //Details code here
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please visit the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn on how to ask a good question. Currently its not clear on where you are exactly stuck and to avoid [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/267137/edit) your question with minimal code for us to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the button, it calls the `submit` method in your controller and then does a full refresh of the page. When the page is loaded (after the refresh) the constructor gets called and in turn calls your `details` method. To avoid this, add an `id` attribute to the `apex:form` and in your `apex:commandButton` provide a `rerender` attribute with the above id.

```
<apex:form id="formid">

<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{! submit}" rerender="formid"/>
```

**Edit:**
The problem is with your getter method `getAccountList`. I would suggest to use lazy load as explained in this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/97065/20832).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But here details() method is executing before submit() method. And also there is no refresh of page. Because in submit method im navigating to another page.